# Where can I find tags data like in Upwork and StackOverflow?

Tags: android, node.js, tags

I want to use those in my application where a user can describe his skills but I can't find the tags.

[image]

Any suggestions where can I get those?

Answer (score 0):

google "tag input UI ANDROID" etc, u know how it works :)

Comment: I am looking for a source of tags themselves not hot program tags.